# Is it okay to use the word "launch" when talking about public transportation?

Tags: word-usage

I always hear "**to launch an app**" or "**to launch a campaign.**"

Can "launch" be used in a situation like this?

> In 2010, Tokyo Metro **launched** the women-only passenger cars.

I have doubts because I think I've never heard the word being used in public transportation. Also, when I asked a native English speaker, he chose the term *to put into operation.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the more [figurative definitions of "launch"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/launch) is "put into operation" (see verb definition 2c-1).  It can be used for any new enterprise, including ones related to transportation.  Example:

> Recently Uber **launched** their "Uber Eats" program, which allows you to order food from your favorite restaurant and have it delivered by an Uber driver.

Because "launch" is a rather *dramatic* term, it's generally used for the new release of some significant service.  It's personal opinion whether simply designating women-only train carriages is significant enough.

It may depend on how big a deal Tokyo Metro is making of the new service. If they have extensively promoted the new service, then "launch" might make sense. Otherwise I agree the less dramatic "put into operation" sounds better.